# how to install squeryl for scala in ellipse?

Tags: postgresql, scala-2.8

I want to run squeryl for PostgreSQL on scala in ellipse. But I have no idea how will do it.
I tried to see on the site http://squeryl.org but there is no mention of the steps needed. Only the list of neccessary files is given.

can anybody guide me step-by-step to run squeryl for scala in ellipse. I am running scala 2.8.0

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using [sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/), add the following to your project file:

```
    val squeryl  = "org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.8.0" % "0.9.4beta8" % "provided"
```

then type 'update' at the sbt prompt.

UPDATE:  Sorry, this was effectively answered yesterday:

[CustomTypesMode is not a member of package org.squeryl.customtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688851/squeryl-customtypesmode-is-not-a-member-of-package-org-squeryl-customtypes)