# Squeryl - "CustomTypesMode is not a member of package org.squeryl.customtypes"?

Tags: scala, squeryl

I've built Squeryl framework with SBT and am trying to use it  with Scala 2.8 and NetBeans 6.9. I've defined an entity model as it is [desctibed in Squeryl intro](http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html), but the IDE and compiler complain that "CustomTypesMode is not a member of package org.squeryl.customtypes". What might the reason be?

Comment: Can you post the code? Also, you say you built squeryl, do you get the same problem when you use the published version?

Comment: There is no published version. Only Maven, something called a POM file, and an SBT project. From these three I am only familiar with SBT.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to build Squeryl, you can download [the jar](http://github.com/downloads/max-l/Squeryl/squeryl_2.8.0-0.9.4beta8.jar) from http://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/downloads.

If you use sbt, you can drop the jar in the lib directory (I just tried and was able to compile the example using `import org.squeryl.customtypes.CustomTypesMode._`.)

Alternately you should be able to this line to your sbt project definition:

```
val squeryl = "org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.8.0" % "0.9.4beta8"
```

Then run update:

```
$ sbt
[info] Recompiling project definition...
[info]    Source analysis: 1 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
[info] Building project test 1.0 against Scala 2.8.0
[info]    using MainProject with sbt 0.7.4 and Scala 2.7.7
> update
[info]
[info] == update ==
[info] downloading http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/squeryl/squeryl_2.8.0/0.9.4beta8/squeryl_2.8.0-0.9.4beta8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.squeryl#squeryl_2.8.0;0.9.4beta8!squeryl_2.8.0.jar (1425ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] cglib#cglib-nodep;2.2!cglib-nodep.jar (909ms)
[info] :: retrieving :: test#test_2.8.0 [sync]
[info]  confs: [compile, runtime, test, provided, system, optional, sources, javadoc]
[info]  2 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (1268kB/60ms)
[info] == update ==
[success] Successful.
```